# SQLalchemy don't want to create a database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, orm

I have issue, that when im passing data throught registration form, I got error

```
/ENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 748, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
\[SQL: INSERT INTO users (email, password, cash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)\]
\[parameters: ('asd@wp.pl', 'asd', '10000')\]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

```
**app.py**
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///oldchool.sqlite3'
app.config["TESTING"] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column("email", db.Text(100), nullable = False)
    password = db.Column("password", db.String(100), nullable = False)
    cash = db.Column("cash", db.Integer, default = "10000")

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        user = users(email, password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()


    else:
        return render_template("auth/register.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    db.create_all()
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
{% endblock %}


{% block main %}
    <div class = "my-form">
        <form method="POST" action="/register">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name = "password">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have no idea why db.create_all() is not creating the table.

Additionally when I tried to check db variable inside the python console I receive this stuff:

```
Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov  4 2022, 09:21:25) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db
'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy>
>>>
```

Also when I'm checking the sqlite3 command like .schemas and .tables I don't see that anything is created

Comment: It's still not working :((